# Failed to instantiate module due to failed to instantiate the dependancy module

Tags: angularjs

**Error is :**

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.customer due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.customer' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My `app.js` contains the following code :

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', ['ui.router',
'myApp.customer'    

]);

myApp.config( function myAppConfig ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( '/account' );
});

myApp.run( function run () {
});


myApp.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams,    fromState, fromParams){
if ( angular.isDefined( toState.data.pageTitle ) ) {
  $scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle ;
}
});
});
```

The `myApp.customer` module is as follows :

```
angular.module('myApp.customer', ['ui.router','ngResource'])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('customer', {
        url:'/customer',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl:'customer/customer.tpl.html',
                controller: 'CustomerCtrl'
            }
        },
        resolve: {

        },
        data : { pageTitle : "Customers" }
  });
 })


.controller("CustomerCtrl", function($scope) {
});
```

Comment: so is the syntax error at end of file legitimate? `.controller`

Comment: it gives me the same error even after removing the extra semicolon

Answer (score 0):

You are already injecting `ui.router` into your main module. Try changing to this:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'myApp.customer']);
```

**myApp.customer**

```
angular.module('myApp.customer', [])
```

**Other things to note:**

1. Are your scripts correct?
2. Why do you have `AppCtrl` after `function` in:

   `myApp.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location ) {`